# Code can't decide where to add number in simulation

Tags: python, simulation

there are 3 tables in a room. table 1 has 1 bar of chocolate, table 2 has 2 bars and table 3 has 3 bars. one person goes into the room at a time and goes to the table that will give them the most chocolate.

i tried creating a simulation is python but when it reaches 4 people it cant figure out where to go as each table will give the same amount of chocolate. i have tried making it so that if each value of choc1, choc2 and choc3 were equal it would just add a person to a random table but that didnt work.

```
numpeople = int(input())
numtab3 = int(1)  # number of people at table 3
numtab2 = int(1)  # number of people at table 2
numtab1 = int(1)  # number of people at table 1
choc3 = float(3 / numtab3)  # how much chocolate people will get at table
choc2 = float(2 / numtab2)
choc1 = float(1 / numtab1)
while numpeople > 0:
    if choc3 > choc1 and choc3 > choc2:
        numtab3 = numtab3 + 1
        numpeople = numpeople - 1
        choc3 = float(3 / numtab3)
        print("table 3")
    if choc2 > choc3 and choc2 > choc1:
        numtab2 = numtab2 + 1
        numpeople = numpeople - 1
        choc2 = float(2 / numtab2)
        print("table 2")
    if choc1 > choc3 and choc1 > choc2:
        numtab1 = numtab1 + 1
        numpeople = numpeople - 1
        choc1 = float(1 / numtab1)
        print("table 1")

numtab3 = numtab3 - 1  # minus 1 to account for starting value being 1
numtab2 = numtab2 - 1
numtab1 = numtab1 - 1
print("total at table 3 = " + str(numtab3))
print("total at table 2 = " + str(numtab2))
print("total at table 1 = " + str(numtab1))
```

Comment: Can you elaborate what happens when a person picks a table? Does he take one bar? All of them? something else?

Comment: @Mureinik when a person goes to that table they will get the chocolate but it has to be given equally to everyone at the table. e.g. 3 people at table 3: they will each get a bar of chocolate since there are 3 bars at that table and is split among the 3 people

Answer (score 0):

I'd hold an list of bars and a list of the number of people at each table. For each new person, you can find the maximum number of bars they would get by joining a table, and select the right table according to that:

```py
numpeople = int(input())
bars_on_tables = [1, 2, 3]
people_at_tables = [0, 0, 0]

for i in range(numpeople):
    # choice is a tuple with the index of the table and the number of bars for that selection:
    potential_bars = (z[0]/(z[1] + 1) for z in zip(bars_on_tables, people_at_tables))
    choice = max(enumerate(potential_bars), key = lambda e: e[1])

    people_at_tables[choice[0]] += 1

    print(f"person #{i + 1} selected table #{choice[0] + 1} in order to get {choice[1]} bars")
```